# Db connection string in MVC 4

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-4, connection

I have the following problem:

When I run my code:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Movies.ToList());
    }
```

I reach an error saying: Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog.

would you be able to help me fix the connection string this is my connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20121214234752;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged what connection  string its picking up?

Below is the connection string from my application which is running at both development and production end

```
  <add name="connectionString" connectionString="server=.\SqlExpress;database=ABC; Connect Timeout=180;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```